# How to modify something in two dimensions at the same time?

Tags: dimensions

One of the biggest mysteries which I cannot understand is how do you modify something in two dimensions at the same time. I tried to solve it myself by pressing two keys at the same time but unfortunately it doesnot help me. If someone doesnot understand what I am talking about: I want to do something like this artist on this video on 0:44 time. The Artist is modifying the mesh in two dimensions at the same time but there are no tips in left-bottom corner so it is still the mystery for uninitiated pupils like me. I searched in Google but it seems to be a secret. If someone of you can reveal this magic power, please tell me and I swear I will use it in good deeds.

0.44
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrYngJmrEFA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see.
If you want to move the object by 2 dimensions.
1. Select the object
2. Press **G**
3. Press **Shift** + **Z** (Or **Shift + Y, Shift + X** demand on which dimension you don't want to change)
4. Move as much as you want.
Do the same with Scale.

Comment: Thank you for help, SHIFT + Z was the spell which I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

- In Edit mode, select the *Edge Select* mode (bottom horizontal menu bar)
- Select both the up and bottom circular edges with <kbd>alt</kbd> *right click* and <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> *right click*
- Type <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Scale with <kbd>S</kbd> and constraint your scale on both X and Y axis with shift Z.

/[image]

Comment: Thank you for help, SHIFT + Z was the spell which I was looking for!